# Map real-time database to List - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing application in flutter for control stock and differences between the system and real inventory.

I need made a Join with firebase realtime database, any body know the way? I'm thinking made a custom method to return a List of ObjectsJoined .

I have two collections in realtime database. One of them have the stocks of products in the system, the other one have data of inventory made by users.

I need compare these two database for search differences between stock system products and inventory products.

I think made a join between products with differences, but i dont know Map a realtime database to a List of Object.

My json in realtime databse have this struct:

[json struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDKmE.jpg)

Appreciate any helps.

sdk Flutter (last release)
DB: Firebase RealTime DB

Tks Mike.

Comment: While the use-case sounds feasible, it's not quite clear to me where you are stuck. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: my problem is that i don't know how to Map one realtime-database collection to a List for use to compare.